# Is there a way i can fix this cURL SSL Error?

Tags: docusignapi

I've been following and using 'https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-php-auth-code-grant' however i get an error:

cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

EDIT: This happens during the ds_callback and getAccessToken request.

I've tried downloading the latest cacert.pem and adding to my PHP.ini file, but this hasnt helped.
My callback url is a secure site with a valid SSL cert.

Some Googling suggested i need to modify the GuzzleHttp Verify with DocuSign's SSL cert?
Not sure what i need to do.

Can someone please assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/ssl-certificate-problem-unable-to-get-local-issuer-certificate-816521128.html

this error happens when a self-signed SSL cert can't be verified.

You do *not* need an HTTPS host for using OAuth as a client.

And if you do have an HTTPS host, use a cert that chains from a known root. Self-signed certs cause more problems than they solve. Certs are available for free from https://letsencrypt.org/ or cost $10 per year or less.

### Not using a self-signed cert?

Then there's some other problem: please update (edit) your question to include more details:

- What OS, what PHP version are you using?
- What is the domain for redirect URL you're using. Is it http://localhost or something else?
- Are you able to install and run the the [eg-03-php-auth-code-grant](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-php-auth-code-grant) code example? If not, that's the first place to start.